# How to log in to the microk8s Kubernetes Dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes-dashboard, microk8s

I enabled the dashboard in microk8s:

```
microk8s.enable dns dashboard
```

I found its IP address:

```
microk8s.kubectl get all --all-namespaces
    ...
kube-system   service/kubernetes-dashboard ClusterIP 10.152.183.212 <none> 443/TCP 24h
    ...
```

I tried to display it in my browser using the URL https://10.152.183.212. My browser gives the error "Authentication failed. Please try again.":

[image: Kubernetes dashboard 'Authentication failed. Please try again.']

I have also received the similar error, "Not enough data to create auth info structure."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that your browser accepts cookies for your dashboard's URL, `https://10.152.183.212` in this case.

With the loose security of microk8s, you can skip sign in and simply select the **SKIP** button.

If you want to sign in for real, get the bearer token for user `admin` from file `/snap/microk8s/current/known_token.csv`:

```
sed -n 's/,admin,admin.*//p' /snap/microk8s/current/known_token.csv
rP8Yredactedk5EU
```

Return to your browser, select **Token**, and enter the bearer token found above. Select **SIGN IN** and enter the bearer token:

[image: Ready to sign in with user admin's bearer token]

Comment: If you are reading this in 2021. The "Skip" option is gone for good.

Answer (score 9):

To extend @John's answer, sometimes you could be asked with an HTTP Basic Auth Prompt, you can find those credentials also in:

```
#/var/snap/microk8s/current/credentials/basic_auth.csv

~/:$ sudo cat /var/snap/microk8s/current/credentials/basic_auth.csv

<password>,admin,admin,"system:masters"
```

The first value (`password`) is the actual password, the user would be `admin`.

Later, you could be asked to login by using the secret token. It can be retrieved in this way:

First, let's figure which is the token name (it is randomize) by getting the secret list:

```
~/:$ kubectl -n kube-system get secret

NAME                               TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
coredns-token-k64mx                kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      86s
.
.
kubernetes-dashboard-token-wmxh6   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      80s
```

The last token (`kubernetes-dashboard-token-wmxh6`) is the one we are looking for, let's get the actual value now:

```
~/:$ kubectl -n kube-system describe secret kubernetes-dashboard-token-wmxh6 

Name:         kubernetes-dashboard-token-wmxh6
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name: kubernetes-dashboard
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: 538fbe6d-ac1e-40e8-91e9-ec0cf4265545

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1115 bytes
namespace:  11 bytes
token:      <token-value>
```

The value of the token field (`<token-value>`) will be the token to login to the K8s dashboard.

From there, you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
kubectl describe service/kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
```

Will return an endpoint. For me it looks like this: 10.1.43.61:8443
Then you can open your browser at https://10.1.43.61:8443 and you probably have to bypass a security warning.

Now you need to authenticate to access the dashboard.

```
token=$(microk8s kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep default-token | cut -d " " -f1)
microk8s kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $token
```

(this command from the [docs](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-dashboard))
Will return the auth token. Paste the token into the login screen and now you should be able to access the dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the token with the following command:

```
microk8s config
```

And get the following output:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ***
    server: https://172.20.10.4:16443
  name: microk8s-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: microk8s-cluster
    user: admin
  name: microk8s
current-context: microk8s
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    token: S2Vyb0pBTEZIMXI0SG1DT1hIWEpoeTc3ZTYvaEZXbXdEMnFaMnZ0eWVXMD0K
```

The token can be used to login into the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

My microk8s version is `MicroK8s v1.26.6 revision 5479`, I can use `microk8s kubectl proxy` and it will giving result like below

```
Checking if Dashboard is running.
Infer repository core for addon dashboard
Waiting for Dashboard to come up.
Trying to get token from microk8s-dashboard-token
Waiting for secret token (attempt 0)
Dashboard will be available at https://127.0.0.1:10443
Use the following token to login:
<long token show here>
```